# Accessing Database objects in Mariadb from different MariaDB server using Stored Procedure

Tags: mariadb

In our application, we have to access data from various tables from different databases residing in separate MariaDB Server using Stored Procedure (Linked Server in SQL Server). It is compulsory in our architecture to keep databases in different servers.

Looking for something like Linked Server of MS SQL.

For e.g. stp_A on Server A referring and fetching data from table B on Server B. another case is stp_X from Server B referring and fetching data from table X from Server A.

How can i achieve the same in MariaDB?

Regards,
Saumik

Comment: Check [CONNECT storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/connect/).

Comment: Dont think CONNECT storage engine will suffice our requirement.